# How to change a matrix from local coordinates to world coordinates?

Tags: c++, matrix, game-physics, physics-engine

I am building a game physics engine following Ian Millington's book *Game Physics Engine Development* and I am confused by one of his implementations when changing matrix bases.

In order to apply rotation to rigid bodies, I have stored the inverse of the inertia tensor in the `RigidBody` class. It is given in local space, however, so in order to use it, I need to transform it into world space.

This is the code he's using (I know it's a lot of code, but I didn't want to alter the original). The function takes in the inverse inertia tensor in local space (`iitBody`) and the rotation matrix of the rigid body (`rotmat`), and outputs the inverse inertia tensor in world space (`iitWorld`).

```cpp
static inline void _transformInertiaTensor(Matrix3 &iitWorld, const Quaternion &q, const Matrix3 &iitBody, const Matrix4 &rotmat)
{
    real t4  = rotmat.data[0]*iitBody.data[0] + rotmat.data[1]*iitBody.data[3] + rotmat.data[2]*iitBody.data[6];
    real t9  = rotmat.data[0]*iitBody.data[1] + rotmat.data[1]*iitBody.data[4] + rotmat.data[2]*iitBody.data[7];
    real t14 = rotmat.data[0]*iitBody.data[2] + rotmat.data[1]*iitBody.data[5] + rotmat.data[2]*iitBody.data[8];
    real t28 = rotmat.data[4]*iitBody.data[0] + rotmat.data[5]*iitBody.data[3] + rotmat.data[6]*iitBody.data[6];
    real t33 = rotmat.data[4]*iitBody.data[1] + rotmat.data[5]*iitBody.data[4] + rotmat.data[6]*iitBody.data[7];
    real t38 = rotmat.data[4]*iitBody.data[2] + rotmat.data[5]*iitBody.data[5] + rotmat.data[6]*iitBody.data[8];
    real t52 = rotmat.data[8]*iitBody.data[0] + rotmat.data[9]*iitBody.data[3] + rotmat.data[10]*iitBody.data[6];
    real t57 = rotmat.data[8]*iitBody.data[1] + rotmat.data[9]*iitBody.data[4] + rotmat.data[10]*iitBody.data[7];
    real t62 = rotmat.data[8]*iitBody.data[2] + rotmat.data[9]*iitBody.data[5] + rotmat.data[10]*iitBody.data[8];

    iitWorld.data[0] = t4*rotmat.data[0]  + t9*rotmat.data[1]  + t14*rotmat.data[2];
    iitWorld.data[1] = t4*rotmat.data[4]  + t9*rotmat.data[5]  + t14*rotmat.data[6];
    iitWorld.data[2] = t4*rotmat.data[8]  + t9*rotmat.data[9]  + t14*rotmat.data[10];
    iitWorld.data[3] = t28*rotmat.data[0] + t33*rotmat.data[1] + t38*rotmat.data[2];
    iitWorld.data[4] = t28*rotmat.data[4] + t33*rotmat.data[5] + t38*rotmat.data[6];
    iitWorld.data[5] = t28*rotmat.data[8] + t33*rotmat.data[9] + t38*rotmat.data[10];
    iitWorld.data[6] = t52*rotmat.data[0] + t57*rotmat.data[1] + t62*rotmat.data[2];
    iitWorld.data[7] = t52*rotmat.data[4] + t57*rotmat.data[5] + t62*rotmat.data[6];
    iitWorld.data[8] = t52*rotmat.data[8] + t57*rotmat.data[9] + t62*rotmat.data[10];
}
```

To my understanding, in order to change the matrix from local to world space, I would simply need to multiply the rotation matrix by the inverse inertia tensor in world space. However, Millington's implementation includes a second multiplication by the rotation matrix and I haven't been able to understand why.

Comment: I have found that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290798/calculating-rigid-body-inertia-tensor-world-coordinates?rq=1 answers the question and states that the right way is multiplying the rotation matrix by the inverse inertia tensor in local space. However, my question is more about _why_ the author did what he did.

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: @csabinho Oh okay, thanks for the tip! I'll try that, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math problem instead of a programming problem